# Is there anyway to have a logic app trigger of an email (apart from the Office 365 trigger)?

Tags: email, azure-logic-apps

Is there anyway to have a logic app trigger of an email (apart from the Office 365 trigger)?

In our case we have on-premise Exchange, and we want to trigger the Logic App when an email is received

Answer (score 1):

I just checked and there is no "Exchange" connector or the like.
I don't know Exchange that well, but as I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42413743/does-exchange-server-in-house-suppport-rest-api), there doesn't seem to be much of a REST API either for older Exchange servers.
Depending on your Exchange version, creating a custom connector makes it next to impossible.

What you would be able to do, is auto-forward the e-mail to an outlook.com/office365 e-mail address and trigger a logic app from there. Not ideal, but it would work.