# Using Microsoft Graph for Exchange integration (on-Premise) C# sample

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I have Exchange 2016 setup (on-premise) and I want to use Microsoft Graph for Exchange integration. My query is does Microsoft Graph supports on-premise Exchange?

If yes, please provide me the sample code and steps. Basically sample code should have capability to send email (code preferably written in C# language).

Any help on this regards will be appreciated.

Regards,
Nilesh

Comment: At least some [research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42413743/does-exchange-server-in-house-suppport-rest-api) would be appreciated. And if you need code samples of a C# email client, I suggest reading [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/get-started-with-ews-managed-api-client-applications).

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, Graph is not avail in on-prem Exchange until Exchange 2019.  I don't have a quick link to this statement, but a search should turn it up.  That said, I've not tried to do Graph on E2019--I've got my hands full extending my code to support O365 for now.